# Rhino Mocks, how can I perform an action after setting a Stub property

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

I have a simple requirement, but I seem to be struggling.

I have created a `stub` that mocks an `interface` that includes a `Property` :

```
public interface IMockIRuleRuningViewModel : IRuleRunningViewModel
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And the `mock` is :

```
var mock = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IMockIRuleRuningViewModel>();
```

Now I want to `mock` an action that I would have put in a setter for this `Property`, and here is my attempt :

```
mock.Stub(x => x.Id).WhenCalled(
    o =>
        {
            var engine = new RulesEngine(mock);
            mock.ProcessRuleEngineResults(engine.RunRule("Id"));
        });
```

But I keep getting this `Exception` :

> You are trying to set an expectation on a property that was defined to use PropertyBehavior.
>   Instead of writing code such as this: mockObject.Stub(x => x.SomeProperty).Return(42);
>   You can use the property directly to achieve the same result: mockObject.SomeProperty = 42;

Comment: You probably want `GenerateMock` instead of `GenerateStub`.

Comment: So you want to execute code when the Id property is set?

Comment: Yes I do want to execute code in the setter

Comment: GenerateMock doesnt work. When I set the property nothing at all happens (it doesnt even set the property - the value stays at 0)

Comment: What's the use-case for wanting to execute code inside the setter of a mocked/stubbed object?  Normally, stubs/mocks are simple stand-ins or placeholders for dependencies.  If you have code that needs to be executed on the setter, that should be part of the unit test for the object that implements the interface.

Comment: @PatrickSteele true, only SUT logic should be executed during tests, otherwise you don't know where error came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to verify the behavior of the SUT (system under test), you should use a mock with the appropriate expectation, and verify that. If you want just to pass a value that may need to act in a certain way, but isn't the focus of this test, you will use a stub (stub will not cause a test to fail).

I assume that you are testing `RulesEngine` in this test (because it is only real object I see). Here is a sample test, which verifies behavior of engine, when "Id" rule was executed:

```
// Arrange
var model = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMockIRuleRuningViewModel>();
model.Expect(m => m.ProcessEngineResults(42));
RulesEngine engine = new RulesEngine(model);

// Act
engine.RunRule("Id");

// Assert
model.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me:

```
HttpResponseBase response = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpResponseBase>();

// stub the getter
response.Stub(r => r.StatusCode).Return((int)HttpStatusCode.OK);

// Stub the setter
response.Stub(r => r.StatusCode = Arg<int>.Is.Anything).WhenCalled( o =>
  {
    Console.WriteLine("called");
  });
```

Since what I'm actually trying to do is model the case where you can get but not set the status code (because headers have already been sent), I don't do `WhenCalled()`, I do this:

```
 response.Stub(r => r.StatusCode = Arg<int>.Is.Anything)
   .Throw(new HttpException("Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent"));
```

You have to use `MockRepository.GenerateMock` not `MockRepository.GenerateStub`. I don't know why.